# man --html - Not showing tables?

Tags: linux, html, man

I recently discovered `man --html`, and am quite giddy with joy at being able to navigate the docs locally in a browser at a whim.

However, it seems like certain objects, such as tables, are not properly generated. Case in point, the first table in `man --html man`:

[image]

Here is what it looks like on the console, with `man man`:

[image]

Generating it `--gxditview` seems to show the table fine, `man -X man`.

Is there something that I may be doing wrong?

EDIT: Forgot platform information, thank you @Bruno9779 and @ssmy for asking.

```
$ cat /etc/issue
Ubuntu 12.04.4 LTS \n \l

$ uname -a | sed "s/$HOSTNAME/***/g"
Linux *** 3.2.0-58-generic #88-Ubuntu SMP Tue Dec 3 17:37:58 UTC 2013 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
$ man --version
man 2.6.1
$ firefox --version
Mozilla Firefox 26.0
```

Comment: By the looks of it, the table is an image format. Could it be that your images are being blocked? Did you disable images through the browser or maybe the Adblock plus extension is blocking it? Try disabling Adblock plus and see what happens.

Comment: My version of man does not have those options. Which version are you using

Comment: More details on what you are running? I don't see this problem on Ubuntu 12.04. Opens fine in Firefox or Chrome. Even with images turned off in Firefox, they are still loaded as it is a local file.

Comment: @Tech1337: I tried disabling AdBlock everywhere and loading the file, but I still had the same results.

Comment: @Bruno9779, @ssmy: I've added the platform info on there. I also tried it with `lynx`, but same result (it shows a placeholder for the image).

Comment: See if you can inspect the page and find the source of the image. Try navigate to the path of the image and see if the image is there or if it loads up.

Comment: Ah... I tried navigating to the image, but it said the file does not exist in firefox. If I try to refresh the page, it disappears, which is most likely because I already have a running instance of firefox and it returns control to `man`, which then removes the file. I fed it to a random program that does not return control, e.g. `sublime --wait`, and explored the images and saw that they stayed... However, I could not find a similar `--wait` option for firefox. Do you know how I might force firefox to wait (without starting a new instance)?